# FacesFileNotFoundException when using IFrame in XHTML

Tags: jsf, iframe

I am getting com.sun.faces.context.FacesFileNotFoundException while using IFRAME menuBar in 2nd browser.

I am getting this error when taking in another browser.

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
-

exception

com.sun.faces.context.FacesFileNotFoundException: /xhtml/auth/faces/xhtml/client/clientImage.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.resolveURL(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:232)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.resolveURL(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:273)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:209)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewMetadataImpl.createMetadataView(ViewMetadataImpl.java:114)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:233)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    com.beo.importexport.filter.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:64)
    org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the JBoss Web/7.0.13.Final logs.

JBoss Web/7.0.13.Final:
```

I used a templage in one XHTML page. 
Inside that templage an IFrame is used.

The iframe consists of a Menu bar with some Menu items.

My problem is when logging in 2nd web browser, session is changed , so the SRC in IFRAME is prefixing older path to hardcorded path.

my iframe src tag below

```
     <iframe name="contentframe"   id="contentframe"  
            width="100%" height="710px"  
    src="faces/xhtml/client/clientImage.xhtml" 
            scrolling="auto"   
           style="overflow: auto;" >
     </iframe>
```

Why is this path prefixing happens in SRC IFRAME ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your `<iframe src>` represents a relative URL. It does not start with the scheme (e.g. `http://`, `https://`, etc), nor with a slash (`/`). Relative URLs are interpreted relative to the current request URL (the one as you see in browser's address bar; note: and thus not to the physical file location in the server's disk file system as many starters incorrectly think!).

So if the request URL is (guessing that `/faces` is the context path; you're not clear on this, you told nothing about the context path nor the actual request URL nor the JSF mapping) for example,

> http://example.com/faces/xhtml/auth/login.xhtml

then the relative URL `faces/xhtml/client/clientImage.xhtml` will be searched in the same folder of the current request URL, resulting in this URL:

> http://example.com/faces/xhtml/auth/faces/xhtml/client/clientImage.xhtml

While still asusming that `/faces` is the context path, then this would yield exactly the exception you got:

```
com.sun.faces.context.FacesFileNotFoundException: /xhtml/auth/faces/xhtml/client/clientImage.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource
```

You're also not clear on what URL exactly the iframe's file is available. Based on the information provided so far, my best guess would be

> http://example.com/faces/xhtml/client/clientImage.xhtml

If this is indeed true, then you should actually be using

```
<iframe src="/faces/xhtml/client/clientImage.xhtml" />
```

The leading slash `/` will make it to be interpreted relative to the domain root, regardless of the current request URL.

Comment: thanks BalusC ,

but i got the solution by putting the path like this

<iframe src="#{request.contextPath}/faces/xhtml/client/clientImage.xhtml" />
-

Comment: @TitusKurian Hello. I am facing similar issue; Do you define `request` in managed bean somehow or it is some EL expression? Do comment please?